# hide links upon click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple links generated at run time with no specific ids tied to them, here is the code which generate links in the loop

```
<%for(int p=0;p<displayLink.length;p++){%>
  <a href="javascript:removeAccount('<%=displayLink[p]%>')" ><%=displayLink[p]%></a>
  <br>
<% }
```

Upon clicking on the link, it should be hidden or removed from the page, I am trying below but its not working.

```
function removeAccount (link){
  $("#link").on('click', function(e) {
    $('#link').prop('disabled',true);
  });
}
```

Comment: change the style to "display: none"

Comment: to hide element you must use ```$('#link').hide()```

Comment: `with no specific ids tied to them` yet does `$("#link")`, what do you expect to happen with this selector?

Comment: removeAccount fired when link clicked. so why do you use $("#link").on('click',function(){}) ?

Comment: You are right but, I am trying all possible ways to hide, hence used #link inside the removeAccount method. But even after trying $('#link').hide() its not working. Moreover I need to perform action using the parameter passed to method other than to hide the link

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeAccount (link){
  $("#link").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('#link').hide();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<%for(int p=0;p<displayLink.length;p++){%>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="my-link" ><%=displayAcct[p]%></a><br>
<% } %>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".my-link").on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this might give you some ideas:
edit: But it is unclear what do you expect to happen other than hiding it.

```js
$("#links a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).fadeOut();
  
  $('#out').html($(this).data('link'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <a href="#" data-link="your link data1">link1</a>
  <a href="#" data-link="your link data2">link2</a>
  <a href="#" data-link="your link data3">link3</a>
  <a href="#" data-link="your link data4">link4</a>
  <a href="#" data-link="your link data5">link5</a>
</div>
<span id="out"></span>
```

Comment: Apart from just hiding, I also need to perform action using the parameter passed to the removeAccount method

Answer (score -1):

You cannot disable a link, it can be show/hide. In your, this is what you are looking for:

```
$('#link').hide();
```

If you want to completely remove the link from the page:

```
$('#link').remove();
```